# Use GitHub's Atom Text Editor as Default Text Editor in Windows

Tags: windows, text-editors, default-settings, atom-editor

I think the title says it all. I downloaded Atom, which comes over as a zip file containing an executable, etc. When I right-click on a text file, source code file, etc, in Windows Explorer and select Open With > Choose default program... I don't see Atom in the list of "Recommended Programs" or "Other Programs" (when I use the arrow to expand that list). If I select "Browse" and use the file explorer to navigate to the Atom executable file and select that, when I return to the "Open with" dialog, I still do not see Atom as an option. I'm pretty clueless when it comes to Windows, so if anyone has any suggestions I'd really appreciate them - thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Browsing to atom.cmd seems to work.  On my computer (Windows 7), it's in `C:\Users\Matthew\AppData\Local\atom\bin`.

You can find the directory with environment variable `%LocalAppData%`. Browse to `%localappdata%\atom\bin`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, mhenry1384! Unfortunately, your configuration does not seem to match mine and a full scan of my C drive did not return a result for atom.cmd.

Answer (score 0):

[mhenry1384's answer](https://superuser.com/a/863236/32245) worked for me.

Perhaps some more information will help you.

#### Installation

You usually install Atom by downloading `SetupAtom.exe` from [Atom.io](https://atom.io) and running it.

I chose to install Atom with [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org). So after installing Chocolatey, I opened a command line with administrator priviledge and typed

```
choco install Atom
```

#### Location of atom.cmd

That installed Atom to

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom\bin
```

where `<username>` is my Windows user name.

There is a subfolder `bin` with a file named `atom.cmd`. Here is a screenshot.

[image: Location of atom.cmd]

#### Always open *.txt files with Atom

Then I right-clicked on a *.txt file,

- selected `Open With`,
- selected `Choose default program...`,
- clicked on the button `Browse...`,
- copied the path `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\atom\bin\*.*` (replace `<username>`) into the text field `File name`
- clicked the button `Open` and
- selected `atom.cmd` in the dialog box and
- clicked the button `Open` again.
- That's it.

Now, double-clicking any *.txt file opens with Atom as the default editor.

#### Versions

- Windows 7
- Chocolatey 0.9.9.8
- Atom 1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of associating your extensions to the atom.cmd file (which doesn't show the beautiful green Atom icon), I associated them with atom.exe, on C:\Users\\AppData\Local\atom\app-\ folder. After first association, Atom app showed on the apps list for subsequent extensions.

Answer (score 0):

i just installed Atom a few hours ago, this worked for me when I browsed through the computer to select a program to open associated files (html,php...)

C:\Users\"USER YOU INSTALLED ATOM ON"\AppData\Local\atom\app-1.2.0\

atom.exe is in the app-1.2.0 folder.

PS: turn on show hidden files to access the AppData folder

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 10 here. I right clicked the Atom icon on the desktop and picked properties. After that i copied the "Start in" location path. I looked over there with the windows explorer and found atom.exe so i typed this in the git bash:

```
git config --global core.editor "C:/Users/YOURNAMEUSER/AppData/Local/atom/app-1.7.4/atom.exe"
```

Note: I changed all `\` for `/` . I do not know if `\` works in git bash, i just created a .bashrc at my home directory and used / there and it worked, so i assumed `/` will be the way to go.